# Where to place sar module?

Tags: 7, database, drush, search

I want to replace some of the links which I am using in my website, i came to know there is a module called [Drush Search & Replace](https://www.drupal.org/project/sar). I have installed also to use this module. But I am not getting where should I keep this module in the drush installed folder or modules folder. I tried by placing this in module folder It will not list out in the modules list because it doesn't have .module file.

I have installed drush in this path

```
Drush script  C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\drush
```

According to the README.txt of this module:

```
Place the sar directory in ~/.drush/commands (create it if you don't have one)
and run `drush help sar'.
```

I tried by placing this module in the `C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\commands` folder also,but when I use `drush help sar` command it will say invalid command sar. Please help me regarding this, Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you cleared the drush cache (`drush cc drush`)?

Comment: One more help..Do you know how can I restrict the replacement only for body field, not titles and all?

Comment: Nope, sorry. I don't know the module :)